# Difference in semantics of computeIfAbsent between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I've noticed a serious difference in the semantics of the `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` method between Oracle's JDK and Open JDK. This is surprising, so I wanted to make note of it, and see whether others have noticed this issue, or if I'm misinterpreting something.

According to the Javadoc for Oracle's JDK (beginning with v8, and continuing to v15) the semantics for invocation of the mappingFunction are:

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically, so the function is applied at most once per key.

However, I noticed the function being invoked twice in my program when the key was accessed simultaneously from two different threads. Digging deeper, I noticed that Open JDK's documentation specifies different semantics:

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically. The supplied function is invoked exactly once per invocation of this method if the key is absent, else not at all.

That's quite a big difference in behavior, and consistent with what I observed in my program. Open JDK's implementation is far less useful, in my opinion, because the resource being constructed is oftentimes very expensive and it should be created *at most* once.

Comment: Doesn't seem that different to me "at most once" vs "exactly once or not at all".  Perhaps you need to be a bit more specific about your concern ?

Comment: OpenJdk runs ahead of OracleJdk, so this change will likely eventually become part of OracleJdk.   FYI, that change was made to OpenJdk in November 2019 - here's the commit, but sorry I don't have time at present to investigate further : https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/dc7d30d08eacbe4d00d16b13e921359d38c77cd8

Comment: @John3136, Read the javadoc snippets again. OpenJDK is specifying that the function will be invoked "once per invocation of this method if the key is absent" while Oracle JDK is specifying the function is invoked "at most once per key". BIG difference.

Comment: @racraman, very interesting! Thank you for sharing that.

Comment: @svcrunch Still not seeing it... OpenJDK is a much clearer explanation but "once if the key is absent (and 0 times if the key is there) vs at most once per key (0 or 1 per key) seem quite similar.

Comment: The JavaDoc was reworded in an attempt to be more precise due to this [discussion](https://markmail.org/message/xaoyyiew45jl5usp#query:+page:1+mid:xaoyyiew45jl5usp+state:results).

Answer (score 0):

> That's quite a big difference in behavior

There is no *behavior* difference. They behave exactly the same.

The wording of the javadoc has simply been changed.

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically, so the function is ***applied* at most once *per key***.

vs:

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically. The supplied function is ***invoked* exactly once *per invocation* of this method** if the key is absent, else not at all.

If two threads are in a race condition for the same key, each thread calls `computeIfAbsent`, so two invocations of the method may occur, one invocation per thread, i.e. **one invocation of the function per call of `computeIfAbsent`**, as described in the second version.

The atomic guarantee means that **only one thread applies the value** to the map, i.e. the result of the function is only applied once for the key in question, as described in the first version. The result of the function call made by the other thread is simply discarded.

As you can see, both versions of the javadoc description accurately describes the behavior of the method. The descriptions don't contradict each other, as they describe two different *aspects* of the behavior.

Comment: I think there's still a subtle difference in possible interpretations. In the OP's question the concern is how many times the mapping function is invoked if two threads invoke `putIfAbsent()` with the same key.  "Once per key" IMO leans towards implying that the mapping function is invoked only once.  "Once per invocation" leaves open the possibility that both threads invoke the mapping function and one result is discarded...

Comment: I would guess (hope) that it's once in both cases but neither wording I think the wording is explicit.  It needs to be changed to clarify this point, or to explicitly leave it unspecified.

Comment: @JimGarrison The problem is that the "once per key" description doesn't claim to only **invoke** the function once, it claims to only **apply** the function once. The function may be called (invoked) a gazillion times, but only the result of one of those will be assigned (applied) to the key. "Applied" doesn't mean "invoked". The other description is less likely to cause confusion/misinterpretation, so I think it is a better description, but they are both entirely accurate.

Comment: @JimGarrison, thanks, I think you explained the issue well. Regarding Andreas's claim regarding the distinction between "invoke" and "apply", I'll only say that invocation and application of a function are synonymous terms, speaking in a general context. Furthermore, had the API authors indeed intended to draw the distinction that Andreas suggests, the statement is reduced to a tautology, since for any map (barring a multimap) a key points to only one value.

Comment: @svcrunch The statement `a = foo()` is 2 operations: 1) call/invoke/execute the function, 2) assign/apply the result to `a`. You don't use verb "apply" to describe a function call. --- Anyway, the key point is: **The behavior/semantics hasn't changed**, just the wording, which is the main misunderstanding in the question. The other misunderstanding is that you expected the function to only be called once for a given key, and neither description actually says that.